# Facebook share bonus

Tags: facebook

I am not sure if this is even possible.

I want to offer some bonus/free material to users if they share my website on facebook.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with that, because it might easily violate [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> 1. You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. And in quite a lot of different ways.

Please supply some more details on how you are planning on doing this. Or at least try and figure it out before asking a basic question like "how?"

Comment: I am fine with anything - client side or server side.

Comment: I don't need complete code, I am just looking for "where to start" as I have never worked with facebook thing. Just name the method or anything, I'll figure it out